# DuplicateMappingException contains physical column name referred to by multiple logical column names on adding passportId to the Student entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

This code is causing the following exception on the **startup**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [student] contains physical column name [passport_id] referred to by multiple logical column names: [passport_id], [passportId]
```

I'm using H2 in-memory database.

Student entity:

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String name;
    private Integer passportId; // adding this will cause DuplicateMappingException

    @OneToOne
    private Passport passport;
    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Passport entity:

```
@Entity
public class Passport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String number;
    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

**Question 1:** What is the reason for org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException?

**Question 2:** Why does adding the following annotation to **passportId** in the Student entity resolve the issue?

```
@Column(name = "passport_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer passportId; // this resolves DuplicateMappingException
```

PS: I know similar questions has been asked earlier but I couldn’t understand the answer for these two questions from those other threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer 1**

The reason is that you have two writable mappings for the same database column and this is not allowed

**Answer 2**

Making one of the mappings read-only solves the problem because then only one mapping will be writable

Comment: I get the same error if I remove `name = "passport_id"` part from the `@Column` annotation. Could you please tell me why `name` param is important even tho spring maps var names like abcDef to abc_def

Comment: What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [student] contains physical column name [passport_id] referred to by multiple logical column names: [passport_id], [passportId]

is the error messages I get.

Comment: The problem is that Hibernate detects to columns that have the same name per naming convention. So you must define the name in the Column that it is the same logical name

Comment: I understand that the logical name `passport_id` is coming from `private Integer passportId;`. Is the logical name `passportId` coming from `@OneToOne private Passport passport;`?

Comment: No exactly the other way around

Comment: So when we specify `name = "passport_id"` in `@Column`, there will be only one logical mapping(`passport_id`) to the physical column of `passport_id`. Correct?

Comment: Exactly. That's like it works